# Which blocks require the Silk Touch enchantment, or benefit from it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft, which blocks:

1. Can only be acquired with a Silk Touch enchanted tool, or
2. Do not drop themselves or 100% of their components when broken, so Silk Touch is still useful, even if the block can be built or acquired without Silk Touch?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

All the blocks that can only be obtained by silk touch are listed in green [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Blocks)

- Bee Nest (not to be confused with Bee Hive)
- Coal ore
- Cobwebs (requires the enchantment to be on shears)
- Diamond ore
- Dirt covered with grass or mycellium
- Emerald ore
- Ice
- Lapis Lazuli ore
- Mushroom blocks
- Quartz ore
- Redstone ore

The blocks that can be obtained in other ways, but are affected by silk touch are:

- Bookshelves
- Clay
- Enderchests
- Glass
- Glowstone
- Gravel will always drop (rather than flint)
- Snow blocks
- Stone

Comment: Other dude forgot turtle eggs.