# Can silk touch shovels acquire all the same blocks silk touch pickaxes can?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In a stroke of bad luck (or misplaced good luck), I finally ended up with silk touch, but on a shovel.

According to this article: [Which blocks require the Silk Touch enchantment, or benefit from it?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41013/which-blocks-require-the-silk-touch-enchantment-or-benefit-from-it), there's lots of things you can do with a silk touch pickaxe, including getting grass and mycellium, which silk touch shovels should obviously be able to do to.

Under normal circumstances though, breaking an ore with a shovel (or anything other than a pickaxe) will yield nothing. Are silk touch enchanted tools a special exception to this - or can I likewise expect not to be able to use my enchanted shovel for any of that good stuff?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you still need a pickaxe for ores.

From the [wiki entry](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting) on silk touch (emphasis mine):

> Allows the collection of normally unobtainable blocks such as Ores , Grass , Mycelium and Huge Mushrooms . **A pickaxe must be used for stone-based blocks (ores)**, while any tool can harvest grass, mycelium, huge mushrooms...

Comment: Thanks, I skimmed the various related wiki entries a few times but that line always escaped me.

Comment: Also note that lower tiers, such as a _Stone Silk Touch Pickaxe_ can **only** pick up ores that a regular _Stone Pickaxe_ can; the rest of the ores are destroyed when mined.